# Sub panel 3 wire and 220Volts

Tags: subpanel, 240v, neutral

My mom just bought an old house (1917). The Main Breaker has 3 wires two hot from a 30amp 220 breaker and one ground going from the main into a sub-panel, there is no room to feed a 4th neutral wire. So there is not a neutral wire.  Can I add to the sub-panel a grounding rod from the ground to a grounding pole into the dirt? I then want to use the sub panel to only hook up the one 3 wire 220-volt plug. The ground to the ground bus in the sub-panel would be connected to the ground in the main and the grounding rod at the sub-panel. The 2 hots to a 30 amp 220-volt breaker in the sub-panel. The sub-panel would never have 110 volts or anything using a neutral and would not have a neutral bus. As long as only the one 220 volts was connected this way would this be safe?

Comment: Well, typically older 3-wire connections like this are hot-hot-*neutral* no ground.  Are you saying you want to re-task that neutral(?) wire to be safety ground, and then use it 220V-only, no neutral wire and no 110V loads?

Comment: What are you planning to plug into that plug?

Comment: Is the wiring between then two panels in **metallic conduit** - entirely likely given the age?

Comment: Yes, I want to make the Neutral into the ground. The sub panel only has three wires available. So I can do hot-hot-ground or hot-hot-neutral. I was going to go with hot-hot-ground leave in the bonding screw and make sure no other connections were used. The only purpose is to plug in a ceramic Kiln. It has a three-prong 220-volt plug. The garage already has 110 plugs everywhere. I would run hot-hot-ground from the plug to the panel. I was going to add a grounding rod to the ground in the subpanel for added safety. There would be no neutral bus in the sub panel.  Thoughts?

Comment: The Conduit between is grey PCV electrical grade.

Comment: And no 110V loads